# next-i18next and redux, where to store the current locale

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I have an app with next.js and next-i18next for the internationalization.
I need to store the current locale and I'm trying to figure out how to do it.
maybe in the _app.tsx or the _document.tsx/
where do I get the current locale? from the instance or the context?

Comment: You can access it e.g. in every component by using: `const {i18n} = useTranslation();
console.log(i18n.language);`. If you need to store it inside Redux you can then dispatch an action with `i18n.language` as value. Where you want to do this, is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Current settings is in i18next.language. When you want to know what language is set just import i18n instance i.e. `import i18n from '../../i18n'`. Instance is created using `i18n.init()`.